# postgres schemas and roles in mySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-schema

I have been using PostGresSQL as the database for one of my applications. To support multi-tenancy, I used schemas and roles for each tenant so as to limit access and prevent data leaks in event of an SQL injection. I am maintaining a single connection pool and then doing a SET ROLE after determining the tenant context so he can access only his own schema. This all works well. However, what is the equivalent design in mySQL ? I saw that mySQL does not have "roles" and a schema / database is the same conceptually, how can I achieve something similar in mySQL ? I ask because I am designing another application and am being told to use mySQL instead of PGSQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mysql does not have the concept of roles, you either have to use different mysql database users and databases to achieve the same logical separation of data. Effectively, after determining the context, you have to connect to mysql using a different myswl user account and a different default database. The drawback is that this solution will render connection pooling inert. Fortunately, in MySQL establishing a new connection to the database is quick and does not require too much resources.

Alternatively, you can use a single database and mysql user account and distinguish between you users on application user account level. Obviously, this means that your users' data will not have the same logical separation as you currently have, but you can still use connection pooling.

As a third alternative with limited number of users you can use the same mysql user account and default database to connect to mysql, but store actual user data in separate databases only accessible using separate mysql user accounts. However, in that default database create separate [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) for each and every table in the user databases. In the create view statement set the definer clause to the mysql user account that can access the given database where the table is stored and set sql security clause to definer. This way you can still use connection pooling, since the connections are made using a common user id to a default database. The client data will be logically separated in the databases. The drawback is that through the views within the default database all data will be accessible and any modification to the underlying data structure must be reflected in the views as well.